# Using express-expose and Handlebars.js gives me Unexpected Token &

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, mustache

I am using express-expose to pass variables to the clientside so I can use them, however the variables that are being passed are being formatted with "

for example I have.

in my server.js

```
res.expose('var some = "variable";');
res.render("home");
```

then in my template i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{{javascript}}
</script>
```

but it gives me an error and chrome dev tools says

```
var some = &quot;variable&quot;;
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! Had to use triple stash {{{javascript}}} rather then double stash.

Comment: Right, `{{...}}` HTML encodes things, `{{{...}}}` leaves things alone.