# it gives "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" when importing express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

when I add this line error appears and if removed error disappears

```
const expressHandleBars = require('express-handlebars');
```

This is the error,

```
C:\Users\Hp\sample-project\node-mongodb-api\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.js:230
                                );
                                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hp\sample-project\node-mongodb-api\node_modules\express-handlebars\index.js:9:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
```

Comment: the error seems to be coming from somewhere else. The code you show is correct. Please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000557/using-express-expose-and-handlebars-js-gives-me-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Node.js are you using? Please check [this issue](https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars/issues/31#issuecomment-627686919).

The error cause by [Trailing commas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas) in function call feature. This feature had been implemented in [Node v8](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-trailing-commas-in-function-syntax-in-argument-lists) so you have to upgrade your Node.js to version 8+ to be able to use `express-handlebars`.